# mysql master/slave fallback scenario

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have Computer A running MySQL/Apache that is handling HTTP requests directly from the web.

Computer A is master that writes data.

Computer B is a replicated slave, only for reads.

Let's say Computer A fails (shuts off entirely) - How do I redirect all public web requests to Computer B? Is that even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Use [clustering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-cluster.html) instead of replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of load balancing. I'd recommend you look into [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/)